# How to create library Pod for few platforms?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoapods

I'm going to create my own Cocoapod for multiple platforms (let's say for `iOS` and `OSX`) as there is no strict platform dependency for it. I've left `s.platform` unspecified in my `.podspec` file for this. When trying to lint it using `pod lib lint` i'm getting error:

```
- ERROR | [tvOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
- NOTE  | [tvOS] xcodebuild:  xcodebuild: error: SDK "appletvsimulator" cannot be located.
```

Obviously it tries to build for `tvOS` platform and fails. I've googled a bit about such issue but i did not find anything.

Any solution? Actually i don't need to test build for `tvOS` so how can i set osx and ios support only.

PS. XCode 7.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is correct but it works for me.
Just use multiple platforms declarations in your `.podspec` file:

```
s.platform = :ios
s.platform = :osx
```

and probably deployment target declaration:

```
s.ios.deployment_target = "5.0"
s.osx.deployment_target = "10.7"
```

Also since the library support multiple platforms you need to choose according 'Base SDK' for 'Pods'.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to target iOS and tvOS, this would be an example.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

s.name        = 'SVGgh'
s.version     = '1.5.1'
s.license     = 'MIT'
s.tvos.deployment_target = '9.0'
s.ios.deployment_target = '7.0'

s.summary     = "SVG Rendering Library for iOS"
s.homepage = 'https://github.com/GenerallyHelpfulSoftware/SVGgh'
s.source   = { :git => 'https://github.com/GenerallyHelpfulSoftware/SVGgh.git', :tag => "v1.5.1" }

s.ios.source_files = 'SVGgh/**/*{.h,m}'
s.tvos.source_files = 'SVGgh/**/*{.h,m}'
s.framework = 'CoreGraphics', 'CoreImage', 'CoreText', 'UIKit', 'Foundation'
s.prefix_header_file = 'SVGgh/SVGgh-Prefix.pch'
s.requires_arc = true
end
```

This requires the Cocoapods library to be updated to 0.39 or above, I think. Note that you can choose a different set of source files per platform.

[Updated in response to comment indicating the questioner didn't want tvOS.].

Comment: originally i wanted to create pod for ios and osx only. tvOS was absent let's say a year ago and it worked previously - just don't specify platform and you're having pod for both ios and osx. now we're having 2 more platforms and i don't need my pod to support them. so the question was "how to make pod support only ios and osx", no tvos support required